# Error on retrieving attributes in sidebar

Tags: attributes

I am trying to pull my attributes inside sidebar with the following code:

```
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->load($_product->getId())
        ->getAttributeText('weight_category');
echo $attributeValue;
```

But I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE (from srdan)**

I work with Josip on that project. The problem is that everytime we want do something with $_product object the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /path/to/template/where/code/is.phtml
```

shows up. We use  code below and error above shows up on frontend:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
?>

<?php if($_product->getSidebar()): ?>
<p>Attribute: <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSidebar(), 'price') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>No Attribute text here!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This means your `$_product` variable is not a valid object. Where exactly are you executing your code?

Comment: In left.phtml which is for left sidebar..

Comment: `catalog/navigation/left.phtml` only serves catalog layered navigation. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate to me. The [other question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/742/attributes-menu-inside-sidebar) includes different code and describes a different behaviour.

Comment: Was your question answered? Then please mark a solution.

Comment: If you found the error, please share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you try to achieve... Normally you can get the current product via:

```
Mage::registry('current_product')
```

Comment: Tried that, I get same error.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: <?php
   $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
   $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
?>

<?php if($_product->getSidebar()): ?>
<p>Attribute: <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSidebar(), 'price') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>No Attribute text here!</p>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: can you check: `echo get_class($this);` and `echo get_class(Mage::registry('current_product'));`

Comment: We tried to echo some text but it isnt workin, so I supose this wont either.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to give an answer to a vague question but I think that you are misunderstanding Magento layout structure.

`catalog/navigation/left.phtml` is used by `<block type="catalog/navigation" .. />`, which means it is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` class. This class doesn't have neither `getProduct()` method, nor `product` property. So in your code `$_product` variable equals to `null` and has no `getId()` method.

This was an anthomology of your error message. Now how you shall do it correctly. Assuming that you want to put a new sidebar block to the left column of your **products details** page you should do the following:

1. Add a block to the layout of your products details page. To do so you have to add the following to `local.xml` file of your theme:

   ```
   <catalog_product_view>
       ...
       <reference name="left">
           <block type="core/template" name="your.custom.sidebar.block" template="callouts/your-custom-sidebar-block.phtml"/>
       </reference>
       ...
   </catalog_product_view>
   ```
2. In your theme create `callouts/your-custom-sidebar-block.phtml` template where you can access the current product object like Fabian already told you:

   ```
   $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
   ```

Comment: We added this in local.xml: 

 <catalog_product_view>
          <reference name="left">
    <block type="core/template" name="attributes.sidebar" template="callouts/attributes-sidebar.phtml"/>
          </reference>
       </catalog_product_view>

Comment: and? does it show up anything at products details page?

Comment: And this in /app/frontend/default/our_theme/template/callouts/attributes-sidebar.phtml:

<?php
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
?>

<?php if($_product->getSidebar()): ?>
<p>Attribute: <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSidebar(), 'price') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>No Attribute text here!</p>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Nothing appears.

Comment: But no error anymore? What is `$_product->getSidebar()`? Do you have an attribute called `sidebar` or what?

Comment: I'm not following either :/ so unclear, do u want to get a sidebar based on products or something

Comment: yes Sidebar is our attribute code.. and actually there is no: $_product->getSidebar(), 'price')   , but $_product->getSidebar(), 'sidebar').. same we want for 3 more attriutes.. 
So we simply want list of attributes on left sidebar when put category view on 3collumns layout.. 
just like here on left sideabar "Shop by" http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalog/category/view/s/shirts/id/4/

Comment: Why you just not enable `Use In Layered Navigation` for your attributes?

Comment: It is enabled. It seems that we cannot echo some text neither in the sidebar, so I supose it is an error somewhere inside blocks xml.. 

<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="left">
    <block type="core/template" name="attributes.sidebar" template="callouts/attributes-sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>